# TALEND: How to extract JSON response body from API into Table in Talend?

Tags: mysql, api, mapping, response, talend

I create a job in Talend to extract data from an API to MySQL table.
I used tRest as input(data pull), and tLogRow for now to view it in table form.

I lost it at mapping the json response into column for each of the field and value.

[image: Sample from components I used in the job]

but the response was in one string line, when it's prettier formatted:

```
{
 "data":
       {
        "user":
               [
                {"id":8, "name":"Alex"},
                {"id":9, "name":"John"}
               ]
        },
       "http_code":200,
       "message":[]
}
```

how can I turn this response and map into table like below

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | Alex |
| 9 | John |

Glad if you guys have the working example too. Or using different components might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to set up tExtractJSONFields:
[image]

Loop path query needs to be:

```
$.data.user[*]
```

And just use the attribute names as json query for for each column.
The output:

```
.--+----.
|tLogRow_1|
|=-+---=|
|id|name|
|=-+---=|
|8 |Alex|
|9 |John|
'--+----'
```

Comment: I connected tExtractJSON with data. But then in Mapping, the column automatically put "Body" under column and empty field under Json query. Did I have to declare column and json query first before connect it with tMap?

Comment: The order in which you do it doesn't matter; just make sure that in tExtractJsonFields, the column containing your json is selected in "JSON Field" (also that your tMap is propagating this column to tExtractJsonFields).

Comment: It works for now as I have to declare the columns and json query. Anyway, thanks for helping me, this is a lot from you! Cheers =)

Comment: you know how OAuth works? That is require to refresh token every one hour? I did not know how to store and bring it to the API that requires it. Appreciate if you could help!